# Adding INotifyPropertyChange in generated EF classes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

So, my classes are auto-generated by EF:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Testje.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Ploeg
    {
        public Ploeg()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Naam { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When one of the properties change, I'd like to do a notifypropertychange. Is this possible somehow without editing this generated class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible, but I strongly suggest to not do this! 
Adding INotifyPropertyChanged in your model will lead to a 
bad separation of concerns.

Use events to highlight that the model has changed.
Have a look here to see how this works: [MSDN on standard event pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx)

Or even better: [MSDN cites Albahari Bros on the event pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527570-03-04.aspx)

In your viewmodel, implement INotifyProperty changed.
Let your ViewModel than listen to the events from your model, adapt the data 
and push it to your view through INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by using a NuGet package called PropertyChanged.Fody. Install the package and then create another partial class adding the [ImplementPropertyChanged] property like the one shown below;

```
using PropertyChanged;

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public partial class Ploeg
{
}
```

That's it.

See [GitHub](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added

> INotifyPropertyChanged

as inheritance  and seems to work like a charm.
Using EF generated classes (Request_Comment is generated class EF)

Example:

```
namespace Requesto
{
    public partial class Request_Comment : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```